# For experiments, how to ensure two photons arrive at beam splitter at the same time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

I'm working on work related DLCZ protocol. In DLCZ protocol, a beam splitter will be settled in the central of two ensembles (you can think it as light source). Ensembles will emit photons simultaneously. Two photons will meet at beam splitter (BS) and trigger detectors.

I'm wondering how people ensure two photons arrive at beam splitter exactly at the same time?

And what will happen if two photons do not pass through beam splitter at the same time? If it is distinguishable?

[image]

Comment: There are methods to make two beams' pulses meet in space and time, is that what you are looking for?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127604/the-dlcz-protocol

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about how practically you make the path lengths be similar. There are a couple of answers, but I'll give you the one I am most familiar from my personal experience (although there are more preferable ways): active length locking. Using principles from control theory (which is mostly learned in electric engineering) one can take the path length difference as something to feedback into a circuit which will try to make it 0. The tool you can use is a piezoelectric crystal, so the circuit will sent voltage to it, making it correct the length.

Comment: @OfekGillon Thanks for your comments. I think it answers my question. :)